# How can I link branches with issues in BitBucket?

Tags: git, issue-tracking, bitbucket

I am using a BitBucket private repo for hosted source-control. I would like to use the issue tracker to manage and assign issues amoungst the team.

With JIRA, the names of branches and issues are linked.

For example, `ISSUE-123` would automatically recognise branch `bugfix/ISSUE-123` as related, and display it in GUI.

Does the built-in issue tracker for BitBucket support this functionality? If so, how should I name my branches so that they are linked?

Comment: [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Response from BitBucket:

> Unfortunately, the feature to link branches with issues to branches is
>   not available on the Bitbucket's built in issue tracker.
>
> You can go ahead and file a feature request for this on our public
>   tracker though: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues
>
> Let us know if you face further issues.

Comment: This seems like a massive oversight, how annoying!

Comment: Guess they're pushing for people to move to Jira.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to link them, not exactly as it works in Jira but it is useful.

You can reference issues, pull requests, users, changesets in commits, comments or descriptions using the following syntax:

```
issue #number  ->  issue #88

pull request #number  ->  pull request #1541

@accountname or @emailaddress  ->  @tutorials

HEX_CHARS  ->  9cc27f2
```

See [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/mark-up-comments-issues-and-commit-messages-321859781.html) for more details.